# Can this method be tested using mockito?

Tags: spring-boot, mockito

I am not sure how to test the first method in the service layer with Mockito as it is using the helper method. Below is my failed attempt at a test: I get an InvalidUseOfMatchersException in the second when clause.
Thanks in advance!

```
@Mock
private EntityRepository EntityRepo;
    
@InjectMocks
private EntityService EntityService;

public List<DTO> getAllDTOs(){
        //first method
        return entityRepo.findAll()
                    .stream()
                    .map(this::convertEntityToDTO)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    //helper method
    public DTO convertEntityToDTO(Entity entity) {
        ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
        modelMapper.getConfiguration()
                .setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.LOOSE);
        DTO dto = new DTO();
        dto = modelMapper.map(entity, DTO.class);
        return dto;
        
    }

@Test
    public void EntityService_GetAll_ReturnsDTOList() {

        when(entityRepo.findAll()).thenReturn(Mockito.anyList());
        
//the second when clause:         when(entityService.convertEntityToDTO(Mockito.any(Entity.class)))
.thenReturn(Mockito.any(DTO.class));
        
        List<DTO>DTOList = entityService.getAllDTOs();
        
        Assertions.assertThat(DTOList).isNotNull();
```

Comment: You can't use `Mockito.any(DTO.class)` for `thenReturn`, `Mockito.any()` calls are only for parameter validations, you have to pass an actual object to `thenReturn` to return

Comment: Which value do you want your repository and your service to return? `Mockito.any` simply returns `null`

Answer (score 0):

`Mockito#any*` methods are actually defined in class `ArgumentMatchers` and can only be used to match the call arguments when setting up a mock or when verifying calls. All matcher methods return `null` (but have side-effects of modifying a matcher stack to be able to properly detect and match mocked calls).

For instance, you might do `Mockito.when(svc.print(Mockito.anyString()).doNothing()` when you don't care about the input or `Mockito.verify(svc.print(Mockito.anyString()), Mockito.never())` when you want to verify that the method has never been called.

When setting up your mock, you have to provide a real value in your `thenReturn` call:

```
when(entityRepo.findAll()).thenReturn(Collections.emptyList());
when(entityService.convertEntityToDTO(Mockito.any(Entity.class)))
        .thenReturn(new DTO());
```

Comment: Despite the changes, it's still giving me the same exception :(

Comment: @MarkoStrukovina can you provide more details, e.g. the full exception message and stack trace? Do it by editing your question and adding the information _as text_.